# Unidentified symbol in music notation

Tags: notation, sheet-music, repeats

What is the symbol marked in red circle?
I tried to search all old hymnbooks, I could not find this symbol.[image]

Comment: Yes I know DS symbol, but the one on top is different defined as DS.

Answer (score 10):

Above the last measure in the piece there is a special type of repeat instruction: *D.S.*. This is an abbreviation of *dal segno*, which is Italian for *from the sign*, where the segno/sign is the symbol you’ve circled in your question.

When you get to the *D.S.* you should jump immediately back to the *segno*, and continue from there.

A more common form of the *segno* looks something like this:

[image: segno]

But (just like the symbol used of the bass clef) this difference doesn’t signify anything other than the font being used.

Comment: Can't believe that sign hasn't cropped up in a question long before this!

Comment: The quarter rest is also different than the common modern version. It looks more like a variation on the eighth rest. All the differences seem to be older.

Comment: @trlkly  Wait 'til you see French sheet music with the rest signs "backwards" :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a 'D.S.'at the bottom of the page.   Dal Segno.  From the sign.    It instructs us to jump back to the 'sign', and that's the symbol we're talking about.   After singing to the end, we jump back to  the 'sign', continue until we reach 'FINE'.   Then start over for the next verse.

It's a minimum set of instructions.  More completely we could use 'D.S. al fine'.   The 'al fine' is assumed.  As is 'then start again for the next verse'.   But it's sufficient.

That's a slightly unusual symbol for the 'sign'.  But you'll encounter lots of variations.  '$' is acceptable if it's all you've got.

Comment: I would be displeased if I saw sheet music that used a dollar sign!

Comment: I know the segno symbol, but the one printed on the sheet above is different, but it is defined as  ds. I've found an old tattered hymnbook, printed in 1840. I'm trying to put the pieces of pages in order.
I see the same symbol but defined as variation.